# Java - Extracting code to a generic method when method names are different

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have a code that iterates on some objects of type `MyType`:

```
// result is of type Map<Long, MyType>
for (final Map.Entry<Long, MyType> someMyTypeObject: result.entrySet() {
   // Do a bunch of stuff

   Status status = someMyTypeObject.getStatus();

   // Do some more stuff
}
```

No I'm adding a flow that handles result of type `Map<Long, MyNewType>` that needs to do **exactly the same thing** while the only difference is that the method that returns the status is named differently (let's say - `getObjectStatus()` instead of `getStatus()`). I can't change either method's name.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
public <T> doIterationWork(Map<Long, T> result) {
   // Do a bunch of stuff

   Status status = someMyTypeObject.getStatus();

   // Do some more stuff
}
```

The problem is - I can't use this method because I can't tell which type is `T`. I thought about overloading 3 methods:

```
public void getStatus(MyType obj) { return obj.getStatus(); }

public void getStatus(MyNewType obj) { return obj.getObjectStatus(); }

public void getStatus(Object obj) { // throw exception }
```

But I can't do it because the call is set according to the static type and not the dynamic type (thus I will always get to the `Object` overload).

Is there a good pattern to handle such case without changing the original classes which is not an option right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really elegant, but you could check the type with instanceof, cast the object and call the corresponding method.

Something like this:

```
Status status;

if (someMyTypeObject instanceof MyType) { // It's a MyType object

    MyType myTypeObject = (MyType) someMyTypeObject;
    status = myTypeObject.getStatus();

} else { // It's a MyNewType object

    MyNewType myNewTypeObject = (MyNewType) someMyTypeObject;
    status = myNewTypeObject.getObjectStatus();

}
```

Comment: That's the solution I started with. It's not elegant on the one hand, but it's very short and has very minor scope. The strategy solution that was suggested here is much more elegant, but requires me to add an interface and 2 classes which might make it less readable.

Answer (score 4):

You don't know `T` inside `doIterationWork()`, but you should known it somewhere upstream, right? If so, you can define a strategy at that point and pass it to `doIterationWork()`:

```
public <T> doIterationWork(Map<Long, T> result, StatusExtractor<T> statusExtractor) {
    ...
     Status status = statusExtractor.extractStatus(result.getValue());
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is a really good one. I decide to go on the other answer here (which was my original solution as well) because in the solution you suggested, I'll have to add more interfaces and classes and while it's more elegant in concept, it might make it less readable when the reader would have to go back and forth between the implementation and the strategy classes.

That's one of those very rare times I decided to go with simple over elegant.

But still - thanks a lot for the great answer!